# Why is the Python repl in Visual Studio Code telling me my objects are undefined?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Test.py:

```
def test():
    print("Hello World")

test()
```

When I run this using the interpreter (ctrl+shift+p > Python: Select Interpreter > target interpreter), it works.

If I then try to run the repl (ctrl+shift+p > Python: Start REPL), I see the repl started in the terminal:

```
PS C:\Development\personal\python\GettingStarted> & c:/Development/personal/python/GettingStarted/.venv/Scripts/python.exe
Python 3.8.3 (tags/v3.8.3:6f8c832, May 13 2020, 22:20:19) [MSC v.1925 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

However, if I try to execute the defined method in the repl, I get an undefined error:

```
>>> test() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'test' is not defined
```

Comment: Why is this being downvoted? Could it be that you simply need to import `test` from `text.py` into your repl session first?

Comment: Maybe I do need to do an import in the repl? I tried `import test` (the name of method). That succeeded in the repl. But when I then called the method test(), it threw a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable.

I also tried to import the module: `import Test` and also `Import Test.py`, and it threw a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Test'.

Lastly, I tried `import test from Test` and `import test from Test.py` and it threw a SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: Yeah, I meant `test.py` not `text.py`, sorry. Try `from test import test`. That should do the trick.

Comment: If you've done `import test`, then you just need to do `test.test()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way #1 to import and use:

```
>>> import test
Hello World
>>> test.test()
Hello World
```

Correct way #2 to import and use:

```
>>> from test import test
Hello World
>>> test()
Hello World
```

If you get an `ImportError` for both ways above, then you are running the Python REPL from the wrong directory.

It's a bit confusing that the filename and function name are the same.

Also it's a bit unusual that there is a call to `test()` at the end of the file (causing the function to be called at *import* time). Typically it's wrapped like `if __name__ == '__main__': test()` to avoid the call at `import` time, but make the call when run as a script from the command-line.

`Import test` doesn't work, because Python keywords are lowercase and case sensitive.

`from test import Test` doesn't work, because Python identifiers (e.g. function names) are case sensitive.

`import Test` may work on Windows (but not on macOS, Linux and many other operating systems), because filenames on Windows are case insensitive.

`import test.py` doesn't work, because it's not allowed to have the `.py` extension as part of the import module name.

`import test from test` doesn't work, because `from ...` must come before `import ...`.

Comment: The problem was the directoy. I didn't pay attention to the fact VS Code did not start the repl in the directory my file was in. Thank you.

Comment: In addition to the reply above, you should also guard the function calls inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` block, if your intention is to invoke the function while running as a script. This will protect erroneous function calls during imports (as you can see, the function was called when you imported the module, I'm sure you don't want the execution flow like that)